# Meshes not visible in render and render is super grainy with black dots

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh, objects

I´ve been trying to fix this now for two days and it seems as being new with blender I´m totally lost. I have this scene with green screen where five snakes(made out of cubes) are slithering through the view done with simple curve modifier. The snakes are visible in rendered view, but when I render a picture it only shows a supergrainy green screen and no snakes, that should be in the middle of the picture. 
There´s only one camera and its activated, the right layer is selected and the snakes are not hidden (the camera icon and eye icon are selected). Thanks for any help!

[image: Rendered image]

[image: Material view]

[image: Rendered view]

Comment: Can you include the file?

Comment: Omg, as I started to clear other layers to simplify the file so I can send it here I found out there was a not visible green screen in front of the snakes that was rendering, but not visible in the work view. I deleted it and the render works fine. I feel super dumb as I should. But it fixed the problem, sorry for taking your time!

Comment: @Lcreature Glad you’ve found the problem - often just explaining a problem can help you resolve it. Please add an answer to your own problem and mark it as the ‘accepted’ answer (the ‘tick’ button). This way it will be marked as answered so others can know it’s been resolved.

Comment: I added an answer, but as I´m a new user here I can accept my own answer only after two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mesh, hidden in the work view but visible in the render, was in front of the camera. Stupid mistake, but the problem is solved. :J